# .csproj not working in visual studio 2017 when upgraded from visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

We just upgraded from VS 2015 to VS 2017 and keep getting the message that our .csproj is no compatible.  I have searched every site and they keep saying the same thing, but it does not work.

Below is the .csproj that is currently causing issues.  I must be missing something.  When you find the nut that this blind squirrel cannot find, I would be most grateful.  I know it is something very simply, but I can find nothing in this .csproj to change to make it compatible in vs2017.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{7651DBFD-9C63-4A3B-AA1B-E62D70969A01}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>AppContainerExe</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>EasyCheckIn</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>EasyCheckIn</AssemblyName>
    <DefaultLanguage>en-US</DefaultLanguage>
    <TargetPlatformVersion>8.1</TargetPlatformVersion>
    <MinimumVisualStudioVersion>12</MinimumVisualStudioVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{BC8A1FFA-BEE3-4634-8014-F334798102B3};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <PackageCertificateKeyFile>EasyCheckIn_TemporaryKey.pfx</PackageCertificateKeyFile>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_APP</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_APP</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|ARM'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\ARM\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_APP</DefineConstants>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>ARM</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|ARM'">
    <OutputPath>bin\ARM\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_APP</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>ARM</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\x64\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_APP</DefineConstants>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x64\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_APP</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_APP</DefineConstants>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_APP</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="App.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>App.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Common\NavigationHelper.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Common\ObservableDictionary.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Common\RelayCommand.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Common\SuspensionManager.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Converter\DateTimeToDateTimeOffset.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Converter\FileNameToImage.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Converter\ImageInfoToStackPanel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Converter\ImageToExtended.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Converter\IntToStatusButton.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Converter\SelectedValueToAuthText.cs" />
    <Compile Include="CustomerInformation.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>CustomerInformation.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Extension\Helper.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Extension\RTMExtendedImage.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Extension\RTMExtendedRepairOrderImageInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="GlobalVars.cs" />
    <Compile Include="CheckInHub.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>CheckInHub.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="HubDataContext.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ImageHandler\EasyImageLayoutHelper.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ImageHandler\ImageHelper.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ImageHandler\RTMDisplayImage.cs" />
    <Compile Include="InputProcessor.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\Annotations.cs" />
    <Compile Include="SigCapture.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>SigCapture.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="SLXCamera.cs" />
    <Compile Include="MainPage.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MainPage.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="StartScreen.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>StartScreen.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="TitleTest.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>TitleTest.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="UserSettings.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AppxManifest Include="Package.appxmanifest">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AppxManifest>
    <None Include="EasyCheckIn_TemporaryKey.pfx" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Assets\Logo.scale-100.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\priordamage.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\SmallLogo.scale-100.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\SplashScreen.scale-100.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\StoreLogo.scale-100.png" />
    <Content Include="Doc\ChangeLog.txt" />
    <Content Include="ExtLib\RTMobileCore.dll" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ApplicationDefinition Include="App.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </ApplicationDefinition>
    <Page Include="CustomerInformation.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="CheckInHub.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="SigCapture.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="SLXCamera.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="MainPage.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="StartScreen.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="TitleTest.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="RTMobileCore, Version=1.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>ExtLib\RTMobileCore.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="RTMobileCore.Serialization">
      <HintPath>ExtLib\RTMobileCore.Serialization.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="XamlSpy.WinRT451, Version=2.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bc9b0c37bf06c6a9, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\First Floor Software\XAML Spy\Libraries\WinRT\XamlSpy.WinRT451.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup />
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '' or '$(VisualStudioVersion)' &lt; '12.0' ">
    <VisualStudioVersion>12.0</VisualStudioVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

Comment: Are you missing languages or SDKs?  When I installed VS 2015 using the default install it was missing C/C++ support and several SDKs.  VS 2015 refused to open VS 2013 C++ projects but the error said nothing about missing features.

Comment: This seems to be a Windows 8.1 project, so you can hit limited support, https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-compatibility-vs